# Converting epgsql results to JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, erlang

I am a total beginner with Erlang and functional programming in general. For fun, to get me started, I am converting an existing Ruby Sinatra REST(ish) API that queries PostgreSQL and returns JSON.

On the Erlang side I am using Cowboy, Epgsql and Jiffy as the JSON library.

Epgsql returns results in the following format:

```
{ok, [{column,<<"column_name">>,int4,4,-1,0}], [{<<"value">>}]}
```

But Jiffy expects the following format when encoding to JSON:

```
{[{<<"column_name">>,<<"value">>}]}
```

The following code works to convert epgsql output into suitable input for jiffy:

Assuming `Data` is the Epgsql output and `Key` is the name of the JSON object being created:

```
{_, C, R} = Data,
Columns = [X || {_, X, _, _, _, _} <- C,
Rows = tuple_to_list(hd(R)),
Result = {[{atom_to_binary(Key, utf8), {lists:zip(Columns, Rows)}}]}.
```

However, I am wondering if this is efficient Erlang?

I've looked into the documentation for Epgsql and Jiffy and can't see any more obvious ways to perform the conversion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, need parse it.

For example function parse result

```
parse_result({error, #error{ code = <<"23505">>, extra = Extra }}) ->
    {match, [Column]} =
        re:run(proplists:get_value(detail, Extra),
               "Key \\(([^\\)]+)\\)", [{capture, all_but_first, binary}]),
    throw({error, {non_unique, Column}});
parse_result({error, #error{ message = Msg }}) ->
    throw({error, Msg});
parse_result({ok, Cols, Rows}) ->
    to_map(Cols, Rows);
parse_result({ok, Counts, Cols, Rows}) ->
    {ok, Counts, to_map(Cols, Rows)};
parse_result(Result) ->
    Result.
```

And function convert result to map

```
to_map(Cols, Rows) ->
    [ maps:from_list(lists:zipwith(fun(#column{name = N}, V) -> {N, V} end,
                                        Cols, tuple_to_list(Row))) || Row <- Rows ].
```

And encode it to json. You can change my code and make output as proplist.